# My text is rendering underneath my Bootstrap nav bar

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using React and starting a simple landing site utilizing multiple pages. I was just able to figure out how to route to my other pages, so now I am trying to start on my home page, but when I did a test text, it looks like the text is begging under my nav bar and cannot figure out how to may it start below the nav bar.

Home:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Home extends Component {
        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <section>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                       </section>
                  </div>
              </div>
           );
         }
      }

export default Home;
```

Nav:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './Contact';

class Nav extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Movie Garden</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <Link to={'/'} class="nav-link active">
                                Home
                                </Link>
                                <Link to={'/about'} class="nav-link">
                                About
                                </Link>
                                <Link to={'/contact'} class="nav-link">
                                Contact
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

I am only using Bootstrap right now.

Comment: obviously text will show below your nav bar because your structure is defined that way , if text is being hided by your navbar then you can add margin-top and it will help

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am still pretty new and some things are not as obvious to me. I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the trouble is cased by `fixed-top` class name on your `navbar`, fixed positioning detaches an element from the DOM flow. So what happened it, the moment `navbar` is detached from regular flow within your DOM stucture, the `<section>` is pushed up since `navbar` is not longer under normal flow with the `div` that contains it.

So I would suggest you do the following:

```
<div className="route-outlet">
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Wrap your `<Switch>` with a `<div>` that will serve as the container for all route outlets. And here's the style for that `<div>`:

```
.route-outlet {
  padding-top: headerHeight; // Type your header height here
}
```

Here we're applying a `padding-top` so that the content is pushed to be shown under the `navbar`. You can use a `margin-top` as well, I prefer `padding-top`, I've had `margin-top` acting weirdly before.

**Conclusion**:

By adding a wrapper `<div>`, you won't have to style every page with `padding-top`. You only do it once and all pages rendered based on Switch will automatically have their content be positioned correctly.